# Efficient way to choose random in or out neighbours of a given vertex in Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I need to choose a random out-neighbor or in-neighbor from a given vertex in my graph using the Boost Graph Library. I receive an index i from an RNG and need to choose the ith out edge (they could be in any order, it just needs to be consistent across calls). To this end, I've made use of `std::advance` like so :

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS> Graph;
Graph g; // Given graph
int i;
int v; // Given vertex
//
// Code to generate random index (guaranteed to be valid) and store it in i
//
typename graph_traits < graph_t >::in_edge_iterator ei, ei_end;
tie(ei,ei_end) = in_edges(v,g);
std::advance(ei,i);
// Now ei points to the ith out edge, and is ready to use
// Return the corresponding in-neighbor
return source(*ei,g);
```

Now this works fine, and I'm getting correct output. However I need to know if this is efficient, that is will `std::advance` work in constant time regardless of the value of `i` since I've used `vecS` to store the adjacency list ? If not, is there an efficient way ?

I should mention that I only need to select a random in-neighbor or out-neighbor, so if you have a way to do that without handling the edges, that would also be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried incrementing the iterator as a pointer and it works. I replaced

```
std::advance(ei,i);
```

with

```
ei+=i;
```

And it now runs in constant time in `i` for both in and out edge iterators. However, the former takes time linear in `i`.

For some reason, despite the fact that I can do random access like above, the check described in the other answer to see if the iterator is random access fails.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure that `advance(ei. i)` is `o(1)`, you can simply add a `static_assert`:

```
 static_assert( 
     std:::is_base_of<
          std::random_access_iterator_tag,
          typename std:::iterator_traits< decltype(ei) >::iterator_category
     >::value,
     "Not a random access iterator!" )
```

This will fail to compile if `ei` is not a random access iterator.

As for the actual question, having `OutEdgeList` (the first template parameter in `adjacency_list`) = `vecS` is sufficient to have random-access `out_edges`. I believe it is not specified whether the iterators returned by `in_edges` are random-access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interestingly the assert failed for _both_ out and in edges. Should that happen considering out edges are explicitly supposed to be random access ? Is there another way to efficiently choose a random neighbor (doesn't have to involve iterating through edges) ?

Comment: I just confirmed with a simple benchmark that neither kind of iterator is random access; the access takes time linear in the index. This seems to be true even when I try adjacency_iterator (the assert fails there as well)

Comment: Well the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) for `out_edges` clearly states that if you use `vecS` the returned iterators should be random-access.. so now I am puzzled.

Comment: I just tried using `ei+=i` to see if it would work and to my surprise it did. Plus, it seems to be O(1) too for both in and out edges. This leads me to think the iterators aren't based on std's `random_access_iterator` but are internally random access. So the assert would fail since we're checking against only std types. Could this be the case ?